# how create KDB range bars

Tags: kdb

unfortunately I'm a beginner with kdb. I am trying to transform ticks futures market data (date, time, price, size) in range bars, which explanation is described in this webpage:
https://help.cqg.com/cqgic/20/default.htm#!Documents/rangebarrb.htm
"A Range Bar chart is a non-time-based chart constructed of bars that indicate price movement as a way to help expose trends and volatility. A bar is created each time a trade occurs outside of the previous bar’s stated price range"

[Image of RangeBars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eItIK.png)

This is my starting ticks table t:

```html
date       time         price   size
------------------------------------
2021.12.13 09:55:22.520 4682.5  1
2021.12.13 09:55:22.520 4682.5  1
2021.12.13 09:55:22.592 4682.5  1
2021.12.13 09:55:22.592 4682.5  1
2021.12.13 09:55:22.592 4682.5  1
2021.12.13 09:55:22.592 4682.5  1
2021.12.13 09:55:22.592 4682.5  2
2021.12.13 09:55:22.696 4682.5  1
2021.12.13 09:55:22.708 4682.5  1
```

I'm trying to create 2 range bars table, so when price make a delta of 2 (from min price to max price) a bar is completed and start a new bar.
To complete each bar the time vary.

I use kdb formula:
select last time, open:first price, high:max price, low:min price, close:last price, volume:sum size by date, 2 xbar price from t

but the result (not good) is:

```html
date       price| time         open    high    low     close   volume
----------------| ---------------------------------------------------
2021.12.23 4712 | 10:41:04.700 4713.75 4713.75 4712.5  4713.75 5839
2021.12.23 4714 | 16:27:59.508 4715.75 4715.75 4714    4715.75 87912
2021.12.23 4716 | 16:59:59.704 4716.5  4717.75 4716    4716.75 78900
2021.12.23 4718 | 16:56:00.940 4718    4719.75 4718    4718    78230
2021.12.23 4720 | 15:59:04.468 4720    4721.75 4720    4720    114064
2021.12.23 4722 | 15:57:43.356 4722    4723.75 4722    4722    87195
2021.12.23 4724 | 15:55:24.700 4724    4725.75 4724    4724    67896
2021.12.23 4726 | 15:55:10.136 4726    4727.75 4726    4726    23351
2021.12.23 4728 | 15:55:04.172 4728    4729.75 4728    4728    26191
2021.12.23 4730 | 15:54:40.096 4730    4731.25 4730    4730    18846
2021.12.26 4716 | 20:17:59.108 4717    4717.75 4716.75 4717.75 303
2021.12.26 4718 | 21:09:08.688 4718    4719.75 4718    4719.75 3529
2021.12.26 4720 | 23:59:58.476 4720    4721.75 4720    4720.5  12145
2021.12.26 4722 | 23:05:46.528 4722    4723.75 4722    4722    9456
2021.12.26 4724 | 19:39:53.516 4724    4725.75 4724    4724    3120
2021.12.26 4726 | 19:10:05.092 4726    4726.5  4726    4726    262
2021.12.27 4712 | 02:48:12.664 4713.75 4713.75 4713.25 4713.75 422
2021.12.27 4714 | 03:04:59.368 4715.75 4715.75 4714    4715.75 2997
2021.12.27 4716 | 04:33:28.224 4717.75 4717.75 4716    4717.75 4544
2021.12.27 4718 | 04:36:56.816 4719.75 4719.75 4718    4719.75 7983
2021.12.27 4720 | 04:48:57.840 4720.25 4721.75 4720    4721.75 8017
2021.12.27 4722 | 07:05:54.468 4722    4723.75 4722    4723.75 6283
2021.12.27 4724 | 07:18:25.944 4724    4725.75 4724    4725.75 6577
2021.12.27 4726 | 07:29:00.936 4726    4727.75 4726    4727.75 1079
2021.12.27 4728 | 09:30:12.684 4728    4729.75 4728    4729.75 4587
2021.12.27 4730 | 09:30:20.096 4730    4731.75 4730    4731.75 18311
2021.12.27 4732 | 09:30:33.416 4732    4733.75 4732    4733.75 15286
2021.12.27 4734 | 09:31:20.188 4734    4735.75 4734    4735.75 8068
2021.12.27 4736 | 09:35:20.584 4736    4737.75 4736    4737.75 5642
2021.12.27 4738 | 09:55:42.292 4738    4739.75 4738    4739.75 30781
2021.12.27 4740 | 10:00:45.252 4740    4741.75 4740    4741.75 44855
2021.12.27 4742 | 10:02:42.868 4742    4743.75 4742    4743.75 15155
2021.12.27 4744 | 10:07:01.228 4744    4745.75 4744    4745.75 13155
2021.12.27 4746 | 10:12:59.244 4746    4747.75 4746    4747.75 20020
2021.12.27 4748 | 10:20:53.264 4748    4749.75 4748    4749.75 25253
2021.12.27 4750 | 10:27:04.184 4750    4751.75 4750    4751.75 8133
2021.12.27 4752 | 10:28:31.980 4752    4753.75 4752    4753.75 10472
2021.12.27 4754 | 10:48:52.712 4754    4755.75 4754    4755.75 18458
2021.12.27 4756 | 11:36:26.204 4756    4757.75 4756    4757.75 44302
2021.12.27 4758 | 11:51:05.524 4758    4759.75 4758    4759.75 39598
2021.12.27 4760 | 11:59:20.924 4760    4761.75 4760    4761.75 44517
2021.12.27 4762 | 12:11:28.400 4762    4763.75 4762    4763.75 11789
2021.12.27 4764 | 12:48:30.932 4764    4765.75 4764    4765.75 30577
2021.12.27 4766 | 15:22:42.212 4766    4767.75 4766    4767.75 34908
2021.12.27 4768 | 15:25:30.632 4768    4769.75 4768    4769.75 52600
2021.12.27 4770 | 15:41:42.400 4770    4771.75 4770    4771.75 61220
2021.12.27 4772 | 21:27:14.048 4772    4773.75 4772    4773.75 42183
2021.12.27 4774 | 22:38:58.564 4774    4775.75 4774    4775.75 43111
2021.12.27 4776 | 23:59:24.392 4776    4777.75 4776    4777.5  28879
2021.12.27 4778 | 23:42:43.300 4778    4779.75 4778    4778    22715
2021.12.27 4780 | 20:01:27.168 4780    4781.75 4780    4780    68495
2021.12.27 4782 | 18:06:48.512 4782    4783.75 4782    4782    52289
2021.12.27 4784 | 16:02:12.176 4784    4784.25 4784    4784    1880
2021.12.28 4774 | 02:54:08.386 4775.75 4775.75 4775.25 4775.75 178
2021.12.28 4776 | 03:07:23.086 4777.25 4777.75 4776    4777.75 3124
2021.12.28 4778 | 03:16:56.649 4778    4779.75 4778    4779.75 4677
2021.12.28 4780 | 03:27:35.693 4780    4781.75 4780    4781.75 5385
2021.12.28 4782 | 09:39:53.615 4782    4783.75 4782    4783.75 6951
2021.12.28 4784 | 09:49:00.299 4784    4785.75 4784    4785.75 23809
2021.12.28 4786 | 10:09:00.008 4786    4787.75 4786    4787.25 55220
2021.12.28 4788 | 10:08:54.026 4788    4789.75 4788    4788    35137
2021.12.28 4790 | 10:07:39.542 4790    4791.75 4790    4790    26044
2021.12.28 4792 | 10:07:30.735 4792    4793.75 4792    4792    22558
2021.12.28 4794 | 10:07:01.984 4794    4795.75 4794    4794    40433
2021.12.28 4796 | 10:06:17.482 4796    4797.75 4796    4796    22644
2021.12.28 4798 | 09:59:29.502 4798    4798    4798    4798    109
```

The result is not good because kdb, in the example table, for the day 2021.12.27 take price and divide it in blocks of 2 for the entire day.

The trick is transform original table time dependent in a table time independent.

I have also try to add to table "t" a column "deltap: (0,1_deltas price)" and then aggregate it by step of 2, but with no success.

For clarity, the futures instrument in tables above is the E-Mini S&P 500 Future, which have a tick (min delta price) of 0.25.

Any solutions?
thanks a lot

Comment: Would you be able to edit the post with an example of the type of output you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: scrapped previous answer

So what you need to do is work out the time intervals for when the price has changed by +/- 2 to create the "bars". This is done with the `times` variable in part 1.

Part 1 is basically a `sums deltas` but when the total delta is greater than the bar you want, the value is set to null. `where null` then grabs the times for the bar/time buckets. This uses `\` or `scan` (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/over/) to iterate through the prices keeping a running total of the change in price or resetting it to null/0 to end/start a bar.

Then you use bin with xbar (part 2 below). This is grouping at irregular intervals. (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/xbar/)

`deltas0` is so that the first delta is 0 rather than 4710. (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/deltas/)

Edit: updated to `>=` in part 1

Edit2: added timestamp column to correct across dates

Edit3: alternative approach

```
// create mock price variance
t:update price:"f"${ y+last 1?x }[raze flip 1 -1 *\: 0.1 * til 10]\[9999;4710] from 
    `date`time xasc ([]date:10000?2022.01.01 + til 3;time:10000?.z.t;size:10000?1000)

deltas0:{first[x]-':x};

f:{[bar;tbl] 
  
  // add timestamp column for 'times' across dates
  tbl:update ts:"P"$"D" sv/: flip string (date;time) from tbl;

  // part 1
  times:exec ts from tbl where null 
    {[x;y;bar] y:(0^x)+y;
       if[(abs y%bar)>=1;y:0Nf];y}[;;bar]\[0;deltas0 price];
 
  // part 2  
  select start:first time, end:last time, open:first price, 
    high:max price, low:min price, close:last price, volume:sum size 
    by times times bin ts from tbl

    };
```

```
q)f[4;t]
ts                           | start        end          open   high   low    close  volume
-----------------------------| ------------------------------------------------------------
                             | 00:00:59.063 00:07:14.804 4710   4713.9 4708.4 4713.9 9186
2022.01.01D00:08:23.650000000| 00:08:23.650 00:10:06.468 4714.3 4717.8 4714.3 4717.8 5433
2022.01.01D00:10:42.424000000| 00:10:42.424 00:31:50.024 4718.5 4719.9 4714.8 4714.8 33448
2022.01.01D00:32:08.135000000| 00:32:08.135 00:56:20.906 4714   4714.5 4710.4 4710.7 40659
2022.01.01D00:56:26.240000000| 00:56:26.240 01:02:38.680 4709.8 4713.2 4709.7 4713.2 11804

q)f[2;t]
ts                           | start        end          open   high   low    close  volume
-----------------------------| ------------------------------------------------------------
                             | 00:00:59.063 00:04:27.040 4710   4711.8 4708.4 4711.8 7133
2022.01.01D00:05:11.841000000| 00:05:11.841 00:08:23.650 4712.5 4714.3 4711.6 4714.3 2712
2022.01.01D00:08:39.812000000| 00:08:39.812 00:09:28.143 4714.8 4716.2 4714.8 4716.2 1881
2022.01.01D00:09:31.499000000| 00:09:31.499 00:15:59.067 4716.9 4718.5 4716.6 4718.5 13352
2022.01.01D00:16:13.128000000| 00:16:13.128 00:18:14.294 4719.3 4719.5 4718   4718   4362
```

The current approach with `f` is creating time buckets/bars and won't include the final value that caused the bucket/bar to change. This is perhaps what you want shown in alternative approach `g`. Below shows how `f` handles the rows in `t`. This also highlights why the bars shouldn't be expected to be exactly 2 as market data is not perfect.

```
bar1           (price = 1)
        +1     (price = 2)
        high = 2 low = 1

bar2    +2     (price = 3) (delta of +2 so new bar starts)
        +1     (price = 4)
        -0.5   (price = 3.5)
        -1     (price = 2.5)
        -0.5   (price = 2)
        -0.5   (price = 1.5)
        high = 4 low = 1.5 // price went up then down before >= 2 delta achieved 

bar3   -0.5   (price = 1) (delta of -2 so new bar starts)
```

An alternative approach would be to use the virtual row number column `i` instead of times.

The deltas calculation is the same but instead of using time, the i/row number is used to generate a list of rows like this:

```
// note the overlap to include the end row as the first row in the next bar
bar1 = 0 1 2 3 4
bar2 = 4 5 6 7 8
bar3 = 8 9 10 11
```

```
g:{[bar;tbl]

  // split table by date
  dates:value exec ([]date;time;size;price) by date from tbl;
    
  // then for each date table do:
  raze {[bar;tbl]
    // get the rows with the deltas calculation and expand out to be a list 
    rows:{{x+til 1 + (y-x)} ./: flip (0^prev x;x)} exec i from tbl where 
      null {[x;y;bar] y:(0^x)+y;if[(abs y%bar)>=1;y:0Nf];y}[;;2]\[0;deltas0 price];
        
    // apply the bar row numbers to the table then do the select query 
    raze { select first date, start:first time, end:last time, 
      open:first price, high:max price, low:min price, close:last price,
      volume:sum size from x 
    } each tbl[rows]        
  }[bar] each dates
  }
```

Example with perfectMkt

```
perfectMkt:([]date:.z.d;time:"t"$(til 20)*1000*60*60;price:0.5 * 1 + til 20;size:100*1 + til 20)

q)g[2;perfectMkt]
date       start        end          open high low close volume
---------------------------------------------------------------
2022.01.17 00:00:00.000 04:00:00.000 0.5  2.5  0.5 2.5   1500
2022.01.17 04:00:00.000 08:00:00.000 2.5  4.5  2.5 4.5   3500
2022.01.17 08:00:00.000 12:00:00.000 4.5  6.5  4.5 6.5   5500
2022.01.17 12:00:00.000 16:00:00.000 6.5  8.5  6.5 8.5   7500
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks very much for your answer. You are right, I'm not so clearly :-), and I update my ask with better explanation on what is a range bar and table I want obtain. thanks again and excuse me

Comment: I think I know what you want now, have somewhat working version that needs updated for dates. Will get back to you later today when I have time to create a decent demo table as only tested on internal market data

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks a lot. I'm now starting to good study the code you posted to create range bars, also if I am struggling to understand why the range is never accurate but always "almost" close to. It is true that there may be spikes, but almost every rows shows a greater or lesser range (high-low or deltas price), albeit slightly. In any case, the formula seems correct. Slowly I will try to "climb the kdb mountain :-)" and see if I get an exact range. Thanks again Matt

Comment: took another look at alternate approach `g` may be what you want

Comment: Matt, I think alternative approach g is not so good as f. So, I have think to share a KDB file with real Tick table of Crude Oil March Futures (Symbol CLH22) from 04January to 18January 2022. Hope this real tick table is useful to find right formula. https://filedropper.com/d/s/svASVfgROqrGgw05WTCRnxlee6Rv15

Comment: took a look at that data, the issue is that the price doesn't change by 2 on some dates. What do you expect it to return in this case? the high low open close for that entire day?

Comment: or do you just want the bars to span multiple days if necessary?